# What is the inverse of $f(x)=x^3-3x$?

Tags: polynomials, inverse

I found this problem in the Spivak calculus book, and have spent probably 5 hours with no progress being made. I found online that Cardano's method can be used, but I doubt this book would require that knowledge, and the problem is only labelled as "pretty hard," not "extremely hard." (with asterisks).

The only thing I figured out was that it's gonna be 3 separate functions. I have tried dividing $x^3-3x-c$ by a linear factor, I have tried guessing the type of functions in the inverse by looking at the graph, I have tried assuming x would be some sum $p+q$ and solving for each variable's expression. I'm about 90% sure there is a much simpler solution that I can no longer see from falling deeper and deeper into these wrong ideas. What am I missing?

Comment: the usual thing is not to find the inverse of a difficult function, rather the derivative of the inverse  function; the latter comes from the chain rule.

Comment: $f$ is not injective: $f(0)=f(\sqrt 3)=f(-\sqrt 3)$

Comment: meanwhile, you should give the exact page  and specify which edition, in case someone has a copy and can look it up

Comment: I have an early edition; chapter 12 is Inverse Functions. pages 210-212  has a few questions in which   $  \lrft( f(x) \right)^3 - 3 f(x) $   appears.

Comment: @ajotatxe, the function $f$ is injective on $(-\infty,-1]$ or on $[-1,1]$ or on $[1,+\infty)$.

Comment: @WillJagy It is the third edition page 238. Problem 12-12(c). Are you saying that finding the derivative helps to find the function itself?

Comment: Mostly he wants you to draw the graph of $x^3 - 3 x$  and make judgements about the possible inverse, in tune with the chapter.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the cubic equation$$x^3-3x-y=0$$ its discriminant is
$$\Delta=-27 \left(y^2-4\right)$$ which is negative if $|y|>2$. For this case, only one real root.

Following the steps given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Trigonometric_and_hyperbolic_solutions), the solution is simply
$$x=2\frac{| y| }{y}\,\cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{| y| }{2}\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $x^3-3x-y=0.$

By Cardano's method that you suggested,

$$x=f^{-1}(y)\\=\sqrt[3]{\frac y2+\sqrt{\frac{y^2}4-1}}+
\sqrt[3]{\frac y2-\sqrt{\frac{y^2}4-1}}$$
for $x>1.$

$$x=f^{-1}(y)\\=w^2\sqrt[3]{\frac
y2+\sqrt{\frac{y^2}4-1}}+w
\sqrt[3]{\frac y2-\sqrt{\frac{y^2}4-1}}$$
for $-1<x<1.$

$$x=f^{-1}(y)=w\sqrt[3]{\frac y2+\sqrt{\frac{y^2}4-1}}+w^2
\sqrt[3]{\frac y2-\sqrt{\frac{y^2}4-1}}$$
for $x<-1.$ Here, $w=e^{\frac{2\pi i}3}$.

Comment: I am not sure about intervals.

Comment: if $y > 2$  there is just one $x$ value that works. He asks the student to draw $x^3 - 3 x$  for this. Same conclusion when your $y < -2$

Comment: Okay, Spivak must have added this on accident or to torture readers, unless Cardano's method is just common knowledge that I don't know somehow